# How do I add a delay to this script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simple script that applies a chat widget to the website. How can I delay this script from running for about 4 seconds?[image: Here is a screenshot of the script]

I tried looking up different solutions but nothing seemed to be the same circumstances.

Comment: What's so special about 4 seconds? Why can't it run when called? Maybe look into the `defer` attribute.

Comment: You can add it to DOM 4 second later with setTimeout i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Wrap the entire script inside a named function block and call that from a setTimeout function:

(run the snippet and wait 4 seconds to see console message)

```js
setTimeout(scriptCode, 4000);

function scriptCode (){
// place all script code here;
console.log("done");
} // end script
```

If you must reference the script from a named url, you can assemble a script tag in js and append it to the page after four seconds. Like this:

```
    setTimeout(scriptCode, 4000);

    function scriptCode (){

    const scriptElement=document.document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.setAttribute("src", "http://scriptAddress.com");
    scriptElement.setAttribute("async", "");
    document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);

    } // end script
```

The script tag will be added to the DOM after 4 seconds and will load and execute as normal